# How do I configure the buffer size and max message size in the ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, rest, wcf-web-api, asp.net-web-api

We used to have these properties in the WCF Web API configuration.

```
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
```

Comment: I was getting `413 Request Entity Too Large` error on ASP.NET Web API project. using `config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;` helped me

Answer (score 19):

If you're self-hosting, it's part of the HttpSelfHostConfiguration class:
[MSDN Documentation of the HttpSelfHostConfiguration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostconfiguration%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

It would be used like this:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
config.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to host in Asp.Net. There used to be a WebApiConfiguration class

Comment: That seem like a likely solution, I'll have to test it.  Ya right 2gb resource in a REST service is crazy. We have coarse grained services which I hate that are ~ 5 mb per message. Yuck!!!

Answer (score 15):

You may want to look at [httpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) section in web.config of your ASP.NET application. They are not named exactly the same, but there may be an analog for what you're trying to do. For instance:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" requestLengthDiskThreshold="16384"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note: [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) is 2,147,483,647

Comment: this is for the request not response.

Answer (score 4):

first i would have done this configuration in the WCF App.config

```
<endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="AddSubService.IService1">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
    <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>

</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="200000000"
           maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then try updaeting the reference in the ASP.NET side which is calling the WCF in the web.config check that the endpoint has changed to  the same.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem making a dynamic binding before like this

```
BasicHttpBinding bind = new BasicHttpBinding();
bind.OpenTimeout = bind.CloseTimeout = bind.SendTimeout = bind.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
bind.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
bind.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
```